# QuickFIX Python Session File Corruption Issue

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj, quickfixn

I am encountering a recurring problem in my production environment using QuickFIX Python. The issue revolves around the corruption of session files (FIX.4.4-A-B.session) in the Sessions folder. The session file is expected to contain a valid date-time format (e.g., `20240108-11:42:01`), but at random times, additional and seemingly random characters are appended(`20231228-22:00:02§♥♥ 0qÄ@☼sS_½•LÕ☼s£↓› GLrµ©5¹vj↕Æ#¿ÈíÜ`), leading to date-time conversion errors.

[image]

This is a critical problem as it causes disruptions in the normal functioning of the system, and unfortunately, the error is being thrown from the underlying C++ codebase, making it challenging to catch and handle programmatically.

[image]

1. **Are there known reasons or common scenarios that lead to such corruption in session files?**
2. **How can I better handle or prevent such corruption in the session files within my Python code?**
3. **Is there a recommended way to catch and handle errors originating from the C++ core of QuickFIX within the Python environment?**

*Versions*:

- Fix version - FIX44
- I am using quickfix-ssl 1.15.1.post4
- OS: Linux - ubuntu - 18.04

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: what is the system current character set settings? and timezone?

Comment: Wild guess: either the process is terminated at that time or multiple threads are concurrently modifying the file?

Comment: @Orenico - The system is configured with UTF-8 and operates in UTC timezone.

Comment: @ChristophJohn - I've thoroughly checked the system logs, and there is no indication of the process being terminated at the time of the issue.

Comment: It might be something with leapseconds...., otherwise I will carefully check the msgs sending party